# Type or namespace could not be found in nopCommerce razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

I'm working on [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/) 3.7 and try to make a [plugin](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/Creating+a+nopCommerce+plugin). But the problem occurs when i add a razor view. I've added dll reference although it says

> The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Using directive is unnecessary.

[image]

Where i made a mistake ? Or What should i do to remove this warning ?

Comment: Try adding in namespaces section of `web.config` in `Views` folder.

Comment: The person who give me the downvote, Can you tell me why it is ? Am i made any mistake ? I think its not fair without informing anything.

Comment: It wasn't me. Did you try adding to `web.config`?

Comment: @JamesP Yes i tried but it is not working, because of nopCommerce build location. I also post same question in nopCommerce forum and get some idea to solve this warning, and i'm trying that way. But it is not any majore issue, application is working as well, it is something nopCommerce limitation according to nopCommarce forum. My post is [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/42310/type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-in-nopcommerce-razor-view-engine.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This is the Visual Studio issue. Intellisense doesn’t work in nopCommerce plugin projects.
You can read how to fix it here:
http://alexwolfthoughts.com/fixing-broken-nopcommerce-razor-intellisense/
and here:
[Razor HTML Helpers giving intellisense errors in Nop Commerce Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175743/razor-html-helpers-giving-intellisense-errors-in-nop-commerce-plugin)